# How to call stored procedure in DB2 with Array as input parameters

Tags: python-3.x, db2

I have a scenario where I have to call my stored procedure in DB2 database. This stored procedure requires input parameters as ARRAY. So can you please let me know how can I call this? I tried with all different options but it's not working and throwing error in SQL query.

1. "call storedprocedure(ARRAY[123,133])"
2. "call storedprocedure([123,133])"

Code:

```
def db_connection(sql_query):
    cursor = db2.connect() 
    cursor.execute(sql_query)

sql_query1 = "CALL STORED_PROCEDURE(ARRAY[12345, 456789], ARRAY[456789, 12345], 
ARRAY[1212])"

data1 = {'ARRAY' : [12345, 456789]}
data2 = {'ARRAY' : [456789, 12345]}
data3 = {'ARRAY' : [1212]}

data1 = pandas.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = pandas.DataFrame(data2)
data3 = pandas.DataFrame(data3)

sql_query2 = "CALL STORED_PROCEDURE(data1, data2, data3)"

db_connection(sql_query1)
db_connection(sql_query2)
```

> Error:1 - Unsupported Syntax ARRAY
> Error:1 - Unexpected argument type  data1

Comment: Are you trying to call the procedure from Python, using the module `ibm_db` ?

Comment: The `ibm_db` module for python does not currently support array parameters. Instead of arrays you can use the pandas dataframe approach.

Comment: @mao Hi mao its not working,

Comment: @mao: Sharing code details below, please have a look: cursor= db2.connect() cursor.execute(sql_query)

Comment: def db_connection(sql_query):
 cursor= db2.connect() 
 cursor.execute(sql_query)

sql_query1 = "CALL STOR_PROC(ARRAY[12345, 456789], ARRAY[456789, 12345], ARRAY[1212])"

data1 = {'ARRAY' : [12345, 456789]}
data2 = {'ARRAY' : [456789, 12345]}
data3 = {'ARRAY' : [1212]}

data1 = pandas.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = pandas.DataFrame(data2)
data3 = pandas.DataFrame(data3)
 
sql_query2 = "CALL STOR_PROC(data1, data2, data3)"
 
db_connection(sql_query1)
db_connection(sql_query2)

Error:1 - Unsupported Syntax ARRAY
Error:1 - Unexpected argument type  data1

Comment: Study the pandas documentation to understand that you use a dataframe __instead of__ an array.

Comment: @mao : I thought you knew the issue but....